# Attempting to install the Intel USB 3.0 drivers results in BSOD

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, motherboard, bsod

I have everything installed from the motherboard disk except for the Intel USB 3.0 drivers. When I tried to install those drivers, I would get the BSOD. To clarify, the BSOD would appear right after the motherboard disk installation utility says the installation of the Intel USB 3.0 drivers is "finished".

Here is my [system information](http://pastebin.com/RbiZma5M). My motherboard is Gigabyte GA-Z77X-UD3H.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drivers on Gigabyte websites and driver CDs are old. Use the driver directly from Intel:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=3467&DwnldID=21129&keyword=USB+3.0&lang=eng

Comment: Gigabyte Website: 1.0.5.235. Intel Website: 1.0.9.254. Geez, 4 versions behind? That is pretty ridiculous. Even more so considering the harm these outdated drivers can cause. I can finally enjoy these USB 3.0 ports. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There are two series of intel usb 3.0 drivers, series 7 and series 8.

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+USB+3.0+eXtensible+Host+Controller+Driver

It's possible to load a series 8 driver for a series 7 "Intel(R) USB 3.0 Root Hub" and bluescreen with the error "STOP: 0x0000007E".  I've verified it myself.